# Generalization in CSS selectors is possible?

Tags: css

I can write this selector condition:

```
h1:not(footer)
, h2:not(footer)
, h3:not(footer)
, h4:not(footer)
, h5:not(footer)
, h6:not(footer) {
    font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
    }
```

but, exists anything easy to use like:

```
(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):not(footer) {
    font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
    }
```

Comment: your selector doesn't make sense. How an element can be a h1 and a footer at the same time? it won't so you don't need the :not() part

Comment: yeah, i do kkk
I noticed this after the post, but it's only illustrative

Answer (score 1):

This is where css preprocessor comes in, you can add variables and functions for efficient development. It also makes your code more organized and clean.

Try using SASS, you can do that with:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    &:not(footer) {
        font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
    }
}
```

It will compile this and generate a new css file that is equivalent to the code above.

Link to sass: https://sass-lang.com/